# Regular expression: Difference between $\emptyset$-concate and $\lambda$-concate?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Given the definition below, is that the concatenation $\emptyset A$ the same as
$\lambda A,$ given $A$ a regular expression? If not, what's the difference? My guess is that if I take concatenation $AB$ as Cartesian product $A\times B,$ then suppose $A=\{0,1\}, \emptyset A=\emptyset$ but $\lambda A=A$. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: The concatenation of sets is a set of concatenations of elements $AB=\{ab: a\in A \wedge b\in B\}$, not pairs. For example for sets $A=\{a, aa\}$, $B=\{b, ab\}$ we have $AB=\{ab, aab, aaab\}$, while $A\times B = \{(a,b),(a,ab),(aa,b),(aa,ab)\}$ (note, that $|AB|=3$, but $|A\times B|=4$)

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak: You're right I'm wrong, but is that $\emptyset A=\emptyset$? Since there are nothing to choose to concatenate?

Comment: According to this definition - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $AB = \{uv \mid u \in A, v \in B\}$. Applying this definition with $A = \emptyset$, one gets $$\emptyset B = \{uv \mid u \in \emptyset, v \in B\}= \emptyset.$$ 
Taking now $A = \{1\}$ (where $1$ denotes the empty word), one gets
$$\{1\}B = \{uv \mid u \in \{1\}, v \in B\} = \{1v \mid v \in B\} = B.$$